# Using Font Awesome in nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to get Font Awesome to work in my nativescript-vue app, I'm following this tutorial:
https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/

It says I have to download a file like fontawesome-webfont.ttf. and import it into my assets folder, can I have a direct link to download this file, I haven't found it in the official FA web.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them from here, [fontAwesome github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome)

Look into the webfonts directory.